# VSIX deploys ItemTemplate on a wrong folder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, itemtemplate, vsix

I upgrade my VSIX project from vs2010 to vs2013, my project contains ItemTemplate, unfortunately my upgraded VSIX deploys ItemTemplates into VS2010 folder, I mean in

```
C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033
```

instead of

```
C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033
```

Anybody knows how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `<SupportedProducts>` element of `extension.vsixmanifest` file in your `VSIX`

Comment: @jacobaloysious Unfortunately I am not able,I have made a lot of changes in my application and almost rewrite every thing and problem is solved. BTW thanks for cocern.

Comment: Good to know your problem is solved...